# Intent.getStringExtra() always returns null

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a service in which I have:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ClipboardWatcherService.this, DeliDict.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
intent.putExtra("searchTerm", searchTerm);
startActivity(intent);
```

and in my activity:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart()
    {
            super.onStart();

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String clipboardSearchTerm = intent.getStringExtra("searchTerm");
            ...
    }
```

But **intent.getStringExtra()** always returns null.

NOTE:
Because I'm calling StartActivity() from my Service (that's outside an activity class) I have to define Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK causing only ONE instance of my activity be alive at a time. So I have to go inside onStart() since onCreate() is called only once. Basically I've been looking for a reliable way to send data from my Service to the activity for a whole day but in vain. can you suggest something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to pass some value from **Service** to any **Activity** class, you should use `BroadcastReceiver.`

Step1) You need to register first that **BroadcastReceiver** to that Activity. For this you need to define **Action** for that.

```
public static final String YOUR_ACTION_STRING = "com.test.android.service.receiver";
```

**Now Register the Receiver**

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("YOUR_ACTION_STRING"));
```

**and receive the value here**

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
      if (bundle != null) {
        String clipboardSearchTerm = intent.getString("searchTerm");

      }
    }
  };
```

Step 2) **From Service you need to Broadcast the message.**

```
   Intent intent=new Intent();
   intent.setAction("YOUR_ACTION_STRING");
   intent.putExtra("searchTerm", searchTerm);
   sendBroadcast(intent);//Broadcast your message to registered Activity
```

Comment: Although your answer is great, but what I actually did was to use SharedPreference to make a shared variable between my service and the activity which were in the same package. I know it looks awkward, but it did work.